# JPA Criteria Query: SQL function call parameters from SubQuery

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, postgis, criteria-api

I'm trying to construct this Criteria Query (PostGIS function):

- Create a subquery from getting the `st_union` (aggregate) from polygon selection.
- Compare a `point` from union of polygon by checking if it is `st_within` that polygon.

**PostGIS Query (works):**

```sql
SELECT place0_.id
FROM place place0_
WHERE st_within(place0_.location, 
(
    SELECT st_union(area1_.location)
    FROM area area1_ 
    WHERE (area1_.id in (10,11)))
)
ORDER BY place0_.id;
```

**Code**:

```java
Subquery<Geometry> locationCriteriaQuery = criteriaQuery.subquery(Geometry.class);

Expression<Geometry> stUnion = locationCriteriaBuilder.function("st_union", 
        Geometry.class, areaLocationRoot.get("location"));
locationCriteriaQuery.select(stUnion)
        .where(locationCriteriaBuilder.and(inListPredicate, inListTypePredicate));

ParameterExpression<Geometry> stUnionParameter = criteriaBuilder.parameter(Geometry.class);
Predicate predicate = criteriaBuilder.isTrue(criteriaBuilder.function("st_within", 
        Boolean.class, placeRoot.get("location"), stUnionParameter));
predicateMap.put(stUnionParameter, locationCriteriaQuery));
```

Code fails because I passed a `locationCriteriaQuery` (`SubquerySelection`) on `stUnionParameter` (`Geometry`) parameter.

How can I get the result from `locationCriteriaQuery` to be passed to custom function parameter.

**Rephrased Question:**
Is there a way to pass a `SubQuery Expression` to a Criteria Builder `Function` as parameter?